# Import large sql file (>20GB)

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I'm trying to import a very large .sql file into my database. The file is currently 20GB big. I tried with the console mysql database < backup.sql but this takes now longer than 24 hours and the mysql server made no reaction anymore.

How can I import such a large file? I think splitting it is the way to go, but how can I split it correctly? It is only one table with several insert statements.

Comment: .sql files are not designed to load files of that size. You will be open and closing a transaction with every line of that file. To do this with any performance you need special tools. Letting us know which database in particular are using will help people point you to the right direction.

Comment: Make a python program that reads it line by line and keeps feeding it into the database. You can also make the program print occasional status messages (% complete, etc.).

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee wouldn't that make it slower, not faster?????

Comment: For php there is such a program: http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/ but it probably can't help you.

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee How would that help? That would make it significantly slower since you would now be doing file parsing AND sql execution AND execv etc.

Comment: how is is this 20gb file being generated? By another SQL server? Is this a one-time operation, or do you need it recurring?

Comment: @gbtimmon and mtahmed - I am thinking that this would allow for timeouts, etc. and also keep the process alive by the status cues. However, the other answers below are definitely more appropriate

Comment: It is generated with mysqldump by another sql server. The engine is MYISAM.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has api driven table inserts built into the language. See below. 
Use this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

You'll need to reformat the file from insert statements to some form of csv or the like, but this should many orders faster then individual statements because it is a way of communicating to the RDBMS "I'm about to upload a lot of data, save the re-idexing and bookkeeping overhead till the end, make sure you have enough space and grab that space once instead of every time you fill up, make sure you use the appropriate locks etc, etc, etc".

Comment: Is there a script or anything to create such a file from my "insert into" file? Or can I export the database to such a file?

Comment: There are plenty of scripts, awk would work if you know that, but good process design would say that you want the process that generates the INSERT's file you are using to generate a .csv instead. I would have to know what that process is to understand what you need to do to get your file in the proper format.

Comment: Okay, I see there is a option with mysqldump. But how can I save the index? Or must I specify that index after the import?

Comment: You might not want to export data if you are trying to do a table copy. The DB should have functions to support that also and that will be your faster option. The route you are going will necessitate build a new index for the new data which will ding some runtime. The truth is a db to db table copy will also likely rebuild indexes, since the hard disk mapping wont be the same and the b-trees will be different.

Comment: So, all in all: What is the best way to transfer such a big table from one server to another?

Comment: Just like you are doing. Doing it like this allows the rdbms to generate new indexes and stats which can only perform better then copied indexes and stats.

Comment: All right! Thank you! One last question: When I import the data with load data: Is it better to create the index on the empty table before inserting the data or should I first insert my .csv file and add the index afterwards? Thank you!

Comment: It would be really hard to say. I don't know enough about the engine you're using to give a definitive answer. After might be better because then the DBMS will only index once and it might load faster ( mass load function you're using should be smart enough to index only once anyway however). Indexing before might change the way the DBMS decide to order the data on the disk and lead to better lookup times. I would recommend before personally, but I really don't think it'll make a significant difference either way.

Answer (score 0):

Simply lock table, then do a copy of this table data files (.frm, .MYI, .MYD).
Instantly u get a ready data file that can be imported to any database.

This method is working very well for myisam.
Not sure about innodb.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the sql file and import it into the database.

Easiest way to split the sqldump file is to use `sqldumpsplitter` software, download [link](http://www.rusiczki.net/2007/01/24/sql-dump-file-splitter/)

or else use this terminal command to split

`split -l 5000 ./path/to/mysqldump.sql ./mysqldump/dbpart-`

Here 5000 is the number of lines of sql commands, you prefer to split. And the next two arguments are source and destination paths respectively. The individual split files will be assigned a name with an alphabet appended to the end of it.

Hope it might help others who has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you consider the following cases while trying to preserve SQL queries across split files :

- A single SQL query can be split across multiple lines so you cannot just split line by line
- A valid SQL query will end at semicolon(;) and mostly, that would be the end of the line.

Armed with this knowledge of these two cases, you can write a simple script which processes your SQL dump line by line and split it out in chunk when it finds a line ending with semicolon(;), or maybe 500 such lines.

I have written such a script for a similar problem which I faced : https://gist.github.com/pratikone/0a8d503ffe893b2111f5a1d70d3999b7

It only checks for semicolon(;) in the line and not at the end of the line, but I didn't have any SQL query which have had semicolon(;) within the query, so it worked perfectly fine. Given that, it is a small change to make if your data can have semicolon in-between the query.